# android studio connects to my phone for junit testing

Tags: android

When I connected my phone to my android studio and run a junit test, it reported:

```
Unknown platform error occurred when running the UTP test suite. Please check logs for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':face-emotion:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///E:/ISCAS_IEL/chinacar/emotion/Perceptrons/face-emotion/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
```

I don't know why and how to solve it

I have run this project on another computer, it built and run successfully, but I can't run it on my new computer.
I have uninstalled my android studio and installed it again, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you check the report as suggested by the error logs on the console?

Comment: Yes, there is no useful information in the report